# on click 'toggle' firing all classes with the name instead of the one clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently having a fairly classic problem in jquery. When a class is clicked (within a ul) all elements with that class name are being toggled.  I really only want the the elements to toggle to be the the element that is click, here is some of my code:

js:

```
$(function(){

    var list = $('.lists');

    list.on({
        'click': function(){
        $('.list-display').toggle('slow');
    }
});

});

html: 

          <ul class ='lists'>
            <li> Soccer
                            <ul class='list-display'>
                                <li> Kick </li>
                                <li> Dribble </li>
                                <li> Pass </li>
                            </ul>
            </li>
            <li> Basketball </li>
                <ul class='list-display'>
                                <li> Shoot </li>
                                <li> Dribble </li>
                                <li> Pass </li>
                            </ul>
            <li> Baseball </li>
                <ul class='list-display'>
                                <li> Catch </li>
                                <li> Throw </li>
                                <li> Hit </li>
                            </ul>
</ul>
```

When I click any li in the main ul (Soccer, Basketball, Baseball) all of the uls embedded in their category toggle. I only want the one clicked to toggle.  How can I re arrange my function to only toggle the one clicked? I imagine I have to use the 'this' keyword but am unfamiliar with using it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/52W8T/)):

```
$('.lists').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $('ul.list-display', this).toggle('slow');
});
```

Also, you have wrong `HTML`, use something like this:

```
<ul class ='lists'>
    <li> Soccer
        <ul class='list-display'>
            <li> Kick </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Basketball
        <ul class='list-display'>
            <li> Shoot </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You didn't put all `ul`s inside `li`, you have two `ul`s like this:

```
<li> Basketball</li>
    <ul class='list-display'>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
<li> Baseball</li>
    <ul class='list-display'>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
list.on({
    'click': function(){
    $('.list-display', this).toggle('slow');
}});
```

I looks for `.list-display` items inside the currently clicked element.